# I am getting error 419 in laravel while displaying something on map eventhough my path is correct

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps

Im creating an application using google maps api that allows the user to add a marker at a specific location
but when im clicking on the map to add the location, all data i get back is correct but i get the response code of error 19...this is my code for saving the data

```
function saveData(lat,lng) 
{

console.log("LAT:"+lat+" LNG:"+lng);

var description = document.getElementById('manual_description').value;
var formData = new FormData();
console.log("DESC:"+description);
formData.append("latitude", lat); //outputs correctly
formData.append("longitude", lng);//outputs correctly
formData.append("description", description); //outputs correctly
console.log(formData.get("latitude")+" "+formData.get("longitude")+" "+formData.get("description"));

downloadUrl(formData, function(data, responseCode) {
            console.log("RESP:"+responseCode);
            console.log(data.length);
            if (responseCode === 200  && data.length > 1) {
                var markerId = getMarkerUniqueId(lat,lng); // get marker id by using clicked point's coordinate
                var manual_marker = markers[markerId]; // find marker
                manual_marker.setIcon(purple_icon);
                infowindow.close();
                infowindow.setContent("<div style=' color: purple; font-size: 25px;'> Waiting for admin confirm!!</div>");
                infowindow.open(map, manual_marker);

            }else{
                console.log("RESPONSECODE: "+ responseCode); //419
                console.log("DATA: "+data); //html data with title of Page Expired
                infowindow.setContent("<div style='color: red; font-size: 25px;'>Inserting Errors</div>");
            }
        });

   function downloadUrl(formData, callback) 
   {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log(xhttp.readyState);
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
                callback(xhttp.responseText, xhttp.status);
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/cacheFinder/public/save");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
        xhttp.send(formData);
    }
```

this is my route `Route::post('save', 'MarkersController@save');`

and this is the save function :

```
 public function save(Request $request){

$lat = $request->input("latitude");
$lng = $request->input("longitude");
$description = $request->input("description");

Marker::create([

        'latitude'=>$lat,
        'longitude'=>$lng,
        'description'=>$description
    ]);


   return redirect('usermap');
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: pass csrf_token with data otherwise add url to verifcsrf middleware to skip this url to verify csrf_token (if you are using post method to pass data to laravel)

Comment: can you show your browser network log

Comment: and also share you form

Comment: i saw something resembling what ur saying... u mean protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ]; @Jignesh Joisar ?? but i tried adding this as it is to verifycsrftoken and no luck

Comment: @Shaielndra Gupta my form is at the top it is shared

Comment: @JohnnyKhoueiry  $except = [ 'stripe/*','/cacheFinder/public/save' ] yes like this

Comment: @Jignesh Joisar no change... still 419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware

```
protected $except = [
    '/cacheFinder/public/*'
];
```

or

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN',window.Cookies.get('_csrf'));`

Comment: i added protected $except = [
        'http://localhost/cacheFinder/public/save*'
    ]; the error changed to 500

Comment: i tried this and it ddnt work : xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
then i tried yours it said window.Cookies is undefined

Comment: use `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` instead of `window.Cookies.get('_csrf')`

Comment: add this `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in your head

Comment: and this also `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: with exception to the content-type, the jquery worked like a charm so thank you @Shaielndra Gupta ... do u know how to make that snippet into vanilla javascript?

Comment: welcome @JohnnyKhoueiry happy to help you have to ask your question with tag vanilla javascript if possible I'll answer to to your question

Answer (score 0):

this is because of https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf  disable route protection in CsrfMiddleware or post valid value

Comment: but this <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> is already in my html ! is that what you mean

Comment: meta is "storage"-only  you need post header named 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' with it`s value or post '_token'

Comment: so add a header of name 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' and what value? @michail1982

Comment: i updated my code to this:       xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/cacheFinder/public/save");
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
            xhttp.send(formData); but still no change

Comment: if disable csrf in middleware slove problem then you send invalid token